# How to get pg_archivecleanup on Amazon Linux 2014.03?

Tags: postgresql, aws

I have an Amazon EC2 instance based on Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03. I installed PostresSQL from their repos:

```
yum install postgresql-libs postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel
```

I've read about Amazon's unexpected upgrade from 9.1 to 9.2, so I added this line to the end of `/etc/yum.conf` so hopefully I can control any upgrades:

```
exclude=postgresql*
```

So far so good. Now I'm setting up continuous archiving and I want to run `pg_archivecleanup`.  However I can't find the `postgresql-contrib` package on the Amazon distro, and it's not listed in the packages:

http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.03-packages/

Is there someplace else to get that pre-compiled?  I tried the following to compile it myself:

`sudo su -
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.2.7/postgresql-9.2.7.tar.gz
tar -xzf postgresql-9.2.7.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/src/postgresql-9.2.7
./configure --without-readline # fails until you add --without-readline
cd /usr/local/src/postgresql-9.2.7/contrib/pg_archivecleanup
gmake
gmake install`

but the `gmake` fails:

`gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard pg_archivecleanup.o  -L../../src/port -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath,'/usr/local/pgsql/lib',--enable-new-dtags  -lpgport -lz -lcrypt -ldl -lm  -o pg_archivecleanup
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpgport
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [pg_archivecleanup] Error 1`

Trying to figure out the `-lpgport` issue led me to some very obscure bug reports [here](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/issues/7) and [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=784281). Tracking bugs in Linux itself seems a little extreme just to compile one file.

What is my best option?

1. Find another source for the contrib package - where?
2. Find a way to compile this module - how?
3. Ditch Amazon Linux and start from scratch with an Ubuntu AMI.
4. Forget `pg_archivecleanup` and write a script to delete old WAL files.

**EDIT**

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk with some pretty tight integration to the Amazon AMI. I'm sure it could be made to work with another AMI, but I expect there would be other gotchas.  What about this option, adapted from [this post](http://www.bitsandpix.com/entry/amazon-ec2-installing-postgres-93-on-amazon-linux-instance-local-storage/):

```
# Change to home directory to download the software
cd ~/
# Get the right postgresql package (Redhat 64 Bit)
wget http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat92-9.2-7.noarch.rpm
# Install the package
sudo rpm -ivh pgdg-redhat92-9.2-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install postgresql92-contrib
```

Does that give me the best of both worlds, an Amazon AMI with an official Postgres repo?  If necessary, I could completely re-install Postgres from that RHEL repo.

Comment: `pg_archivecleanup` requires other bits of PostgreSQL, specifically `libpgport`. You'd have to compile the top-level source directory first ("make"), before attempting to compile `pg_archivecleanup`. Personally I'd take option #5 - use a better distro, and then use apt.postgresql.org or yum.postgresql.org packages.

Comment: Thanks for the info on `libpgport`. I've updated the question after some more research on using a different repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of this [AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=551404), I realized that this line in `/etc/yum.conf`

```
exclude=postgresql*
```

excludes not only updates but installs.  Once I commented that out (temporarily), I was able to use

```
sudo yum install postgresql-contrib
```

to install postgresql-contrib directly from the Amazon repo--no need for changing the repository or the operating system.